# Why does a for loop return only the first item when a list comprehension returns everything?

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to use zip() to combine words together but wondering why the below codes lead to different results?

1)

```
def concatenate(L1,L2,connector):
    for (word1,word2) in zip(L1,L2):
        return [word1+connector+word2]

concatenate(['A','B'],['a','b'],'-')
```

expecting `['A-a','B-b']` but I got: `['A-a']` only

2)

```
def concatenate(L1,L2,connector):
    return [word1+connector+word2 for (word1,word2) in zip(L1,L2)]
```

I got: `['A-a', 'B-b']`

Comment: You're returning on the first iteration of the loop in the first version.

Comment: `return` ends the function, so it never completes the loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] the question to have a more descriptive title, like for example, 'Why does "return" stop the loop?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` exits the function. If you want to return multiple values, you could use [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators), though it might be overkill for your purposes:

```
def concatenate(L1, L2, connector):
    for word1, word2 in zip(L1, L2):
        yield word1+connector+word2

list(concatenate(['A','B'], ['a','b'], '-'))  # -> ['A-a', 'B-b']
```

Note that you need to add `list()` on the function call to actually get a list out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to just return the first iteration.

```
def concatenate(L1,L2,connector):
    merge=[]
    for (word1,word2) in zip(L1,L2):
        merge=merge+[word1+connector+word2]
    return(merge)

print(concatenate(['A','B'],['a','b'],'-'))
```

and this code which will run all the iterations:

```
def concatenate(L1,L2,connector):
    return [word1+connector+word2 for (word1,word2) in zip(L1,L2)]
    

print(concatenate(['A','B'],['a','b'],'-'))
```

In the first code, I just add the last string into an array and return the variable.

Comment: `return` is a statement, not a function, so for clarity, don't put parens on its arguments: `return merge`

Comment: That way of appending to a list is really overcomplicated. Just use `merge.append(word1+connector+word2)`

Comment: oh thanks about the suggestion.